# Laplace transform of $f(t)=\left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right|$?

Tags: laplace-transform, periodic-functions

If you are given a rectified sine wave,  $$f(t)=\left|\sin\frac{t}{2}\right|$$  how do you find the Laplace transform of this?

I tried using the equation $$L\{ f(t)\} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-sT}} \int_0^T f(t) e^{-sT}\, dt$$ with period $T= 2\pi$ but I am not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure go back to first principles:

$$L[f](s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} \ dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} |\sin(t/2)| e^{-st} \ dt \ = \ ...$$

Can you take it from here?

---

Added: The last expression is equal to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(t/2) e^{-s(t+2n\pi)} \ dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2n\pi s} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(t/2) e^{-st} \ dt $$

$$ = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-2\pi s}} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(t/2) e^{-st} \ dt$$

How about now?

Comment: Sorry. I don't think I would be able to. That is bit too complex for me.

Comment: Does this take into account the absolute value signs?